# How do I open firewall ports for Windows file sharing?

Tags: firewall, file-sharing, port-forwarding, credentials, version-control

This is required for Visual SourceSafe to work.

I need to know what ports need to be open to the outside, so Windows file sharing can respond to users in the public internet. Users need to be prompted for domain credentials when they try to connect, of course.

Someone should be able to type `\\MY-PUBLIC-IP\` and get prompted for domain credentials, after which a list of the available shares on my server would be displayed. Furthermore, public users should be able to type `\\MY-PUBLIC-IP\HiddenShare$\` to get to shared folders that are hidden from the public directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would absolutely never set this up: you're asking for big time trouble, if not a complete ownage of your system, certainly a case where you're servers would be incessantly pounded by bots and port scanners, likely causing a Denial of Service; having SMB/CIFS open to the World is a Very Bad Thing.

Look into setting up VPN for your remote developers or possibly [this](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/SAW_Overview.aspx) product*.

*I've never used this product before, but apparently it's "Microsoft recommended".

Comment: How is this an answer to the question being asked?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Although andol is right to say that this isn't a direct answer to the question, I will probably persue a remote access solution in the end. I know that VSS supports web access of some kind using HTTP(S?), and I just need to figure out how to get that to work with IIS on my server.